# RecyclerView#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, dimension, onmeasure

I have a fragment with `RecyclerView` attached with the `LinearSnapHelper` so to get the view in the center and highlight it by scaling its size.

it is working fine , but when pop this fragment from backstack on back press, it throws following exception.

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: View with id 2131689939: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19746)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1117)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1420)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:482)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
```

The relevant code for `RecyclerView is` as

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/81a2ae091ded158839b6353ddb03163f/raw/1aff18064d4de4e42b79aa50ff8d44bd6df365a9/Main.java

Comment: Did you find something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that this is because we are calling `RecyclerView.setLayoutManager()` with a `LayoutManager` that already has a `RecyclerView`.

```
public void setLayoutManager(LayoutManager layout) {
    ...
    if (layout != null) {
        if (layout.mRecyclerView != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("LayoutManager " + layout
                    + " is already attached to a RecyclerView:"
                    + layout.mRecyclerView.exceptionLabel());
        }
        mLayout.setRecyclerView(this);
        if (mIsAttached) {
            mLayout.dispatchAttachedToWindow(this);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But for a reason that I don't understand, the exception that is printed in Logcat is

```
UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: View with id 2131231433: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()`
```

Maybe something catches this exception and *throws* this one instead (without *cause*)?

Comment: yes . the Layout manager needed to be reinitialized. thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by simply calling `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));` and it worked, I hope it'll help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just fixed it as @Kevin Robatel mentioned.
In my case, I was initializing the layout manager only once in the onCreate(), then using it onViewCreated() or onResume()(i.e, in multiple places).

So, the fix is "**re-initialize the layout manager everytime you need to set the layout manager**".

It's a lessen for me too, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have more than 1 recycler view but i create linearlayout manager only once.

i create linearlayout manager for each recycler view and it worked.

thanks.